# Applying WAF rules to CloudFront still leaves back-end unprotected?

Tags: amazon-web-services

It appears that applying WAF rules to a CloudFront distribution still leaves the back-end Application Load Balancer unprotected.

It is not clear in the AWS Console, how to transitively apply the WAF rules, and/or lockdown the ALB to only accept connections to CloudFront.

Is there ANY documentation or anecdotal best-practices on this?

Answer (score 2):

**IP Restriction**

You protect your ALB / instance using security groups, which whitelist only the CloudFront IP addresses. This list changes regularly, but AWS have the [CloudFront Update Security Group Lambda](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cloudfront-samples/tree/master/update_security_groups_lambda), which helps you keep the list of IPs up to date. It doesn't do initial population of IPs though.

I'm not entirely sure the best way to do the initial security group IP population. You have to have to get the [AWS IP list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) and extract CloudFront IPs out of it, which [This script](https://aws.nz/projects/filter-ip-ranges/) may be useful for. This seems like a problem someone should have solved already, so some searching may find a solution. MLu might know, he'll probably comment in the next day or two.

I usually use NACLs to allow only the ports / protocols through into the subnet with the ALB, then security groups for CloudFront IPs. Don't forget to whitelist any administration required from public IPs, though best practice is to use a bastion host for public access.

**WAF**

AWS WAF, or another WAF, can protect against application layer attacks. They can also mitigate DDOS attacks.

**Other**

As you pointed out in the comments, an attacker can create their own CF distribution which means they can attack the server directly. CloudFront / Shield will still apply DDOS protection, which mitigates that somewhat.

Security has to be in layers. You need a secure, scalable application layer in addition to the CDN / WAF. You can rate limit at the application layer, use on-instance firewalls, IDS / IPS.

There's a host of things you can do to make it more difficult for an attacker. If you're online, you're vulnerable to attacks. This is why secure offsite backups and a rehearsed recovery plan are also important.

Comment: That still leaves the ALB open to attack via CloudFront itself, as an attacker can create their own CF distribution which will satisfy the CloudFront IP whitelist. The attack doesn't require any special access or credentials, just knowledge of the origin endpoint.

Comment: True. If someone wants to attack you there's really no way to prevent it, if you want your website to be on the internet. You can make it more difficult. I'll edit my answer to give a bit more information. You have to ensure your application is secure, and your application and infrastructure can scale to absorb a DDOS.